Why is my socket losing its type when passed into a function?
I receive the error:

[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

def main():
    test_sock = connToDevice("TEST")

    resetRobot(test_sock)

def connToDevice(device):
    if(device == "TEST"):    
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as test_sock:
            try:
                test_sock.connect((HOST_CONTROLLER, PORT))
                print("Connected to TEST")
                return test_sock
            except:
                print("Socket could not be opened")

def resetRobot(sock):
    cmd = b'RS1'
    sock.sendall(cmd)
    reply = sock.recv(1024).decode()
    if reply == "OK":
        print("Command accepted - RS1")
    elif reply == "NAK":
        print("Not accepted - RS1")
    else:
        print("Error - RS1")
        print("Reply: " + reply)

After investigating, it seems that my sock parameter that I pass into resetRobot() is no longer a socket object type, however, test_sock in main() is. I don't understand why passing a socket into a function causes it to lose its type.
I have tried seeing if I can force the type, but I'm not really sure what Python is doing internally to cause this issue. I believe it to be a scope issue, but I'm not sure how to remedy it. It feels like it should be obvious that passing a socket object into a function should allow you to utilize the socket object in that function.

You’ve used a with block to automatically destroy the socket once you leave it.

Read the linked question for details on how with works, but to fix it, create the socket with test_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) and then you can do with connToDevice("TEST") as test_sock: resetRobot(test_sock) in main.

The entire purpose of using the with statement to create/open a resource is that the resource will be destroyed/closed when the with block exits.  A return statement certainly counts as exiting the block.  If you do not want that behavior, why are you using the with statement?

Thank you so much for the help. I was just using with  based on examples of creating a socket - it was not my intention as I did not understand the behavior of that keyword.
I find it weird how the type remains "socket" even after the return. In main() I can still use socket methods.

It's still a socket, just a closed one.
